# С какой буквы пишется "мир"

Tags: прописная-строчная

С прописной или строчной пишется слово *мир* в значении *Вселенная*?

Примеры употребления: 1) так вы спасёте этот мир; 2) мир содрогнулся; 3) устройство этого мира.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всех предложенных Вами примерах принято писать ***мир*** со строчной буквы.

См. *Лопатин В.В. и др. "Прописная или строчная. Орфографический словарь-справочник". М., 2007:*

> *1.* **мир,** -а *(Вселенная; земля; отсутствие вражды)...*